# Where is my hot-keyed shortcut?

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts, hotkeys

I made a shortcut hotkey, so `ctrl+1` opened a certain file. I have since deleted the original file, but I have forgotten where I put the shortcut. Is there any way of finding out where it is?

The fact that the key combination is assigned to a shortcut means I can't use it in other applications, which is very annoying. I don't know what the name of the original file I assigned the shortcut to was (it was just a throwaway file for testing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shortcut files with associated hotkeys only trigger from the following directories:

- User/My Documents
- User/Desktop
- User/Start Menu
- Allusers/My Documents
- AllUsers/Desktop
- AllUsers/Start Menu

Additionally there is a bug in some versions of Windows where deleting the shortcut confuses Windows so that it won't recognise that keyboard combination anymore. The solution to this is to either restart explorer.exe or to log-off and re-login.